# how to merge 2 related tables even foreign key is null in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Could you please help,

I have 2 tables that you can see on the screenshot below.

I need to get all data from from both tables if cargo.truck_id equals trucks.id, even if cargo.truck_id NOT equals trucks.id I also need to get all rows from cargo table.

I have tried code below, but it retunrs rows only when cargo.truck_id equals trucks.id, and not returns rows from cargo table when cargo.truck_id = null;

```
  SELECT * FROM Tables.cargo INNER JOIN trucks ON cargo.truck_id=trucks.id  OR  cargo.truck_id=null;
```

I have 2 related tables.

[image]

Could you please suggest how to write correct request?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: LEFT JOIN not inner join.Please publish table definitions , sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Thaknks, LEFT JOIN works well!